# Save username/email to iCloud Keychain ios 12

Tags: swift, web, credentials, keychain, ios12

I'm develop an app that has sign up screen that contain :
First Name, Last Name, Email (ContentType: username/email), password.

in ios12 it's automatically save the `lastname` and password to keychain but i expect that keychain should save the `username/email` not the `lastname`.

Currently i use some tricky part by using `SecAddSharedWebCredential`
Using that method will result that app will keep 2 account on keychain.

Anyone has suggestion how to save the username/email and password to keychain without `SecAddSharedWebCredential`?